# autocapitalize="none" doesn't work for <input type="search"> in Firefox on Android

Tags: html, html-input, firefox-android, autocapitalize

This simple code doesn't work in Firefox on Android as expected:

```html
<input type="search" autocapitalize="none">
```

**Expected behavior:** input value is not automatically capitalized

**Actual behavior:** input value is capitalized

Am I missing something or it's a bug in Firefox on Android?

---

PS. I just noticed that SO code snippets don't work on mobile, here's the live demo for testing purposes: https://gleaming-kitty.glitch.me/

Comment: Looks pretty much like a bug. input type text doesn't autocapitalize in firefox android.  May be you can use that as a fallback?

Comment: input type text works as expected, by I can't use it as a fallback

Answer (score 2):

This does in fact seem to be a missing feature on Firefox for Android. Here's the bug report. Feel free to vote and add yourself to CC (or maybe even contribute a patch).

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1425291

I also made a simple demo for testing the autocapitalize attribute:

https://jsitor.com/t3mzs47BZ

Answer (score 1):

**I would try `autocapitalize="none"` and `autocapitalize="off"` simultaneously.**

If that still doesn't work then there is probably a bug in the version of Firefox for Android you're using.

Comment: autocapitalize="none" is supported by all browsers and autocapitalize="off" is actually deprcated: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-autocapitalize